# Get label of selection with digit/registry in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I think I am using digit/registry stuff and I have this select(drop-down list) which when I do JSON.stringify() on it, part of the information it gives is this:

```
   "_optionsMdl" : [
      {
         "label" : "558Label",
         "selected" : false,
         "value" : 558
      },
      {
         "label" : "739Label",
         "selected" : true,
         "value" : 739
      },
```

How do I get the selected label value?
In above example, the "739Label" is selected, and I want some way to get that label value.

This is what I have that gives part of above output:
        var cat52 = registry.byId("c52");
        console.log("cat52="+JSON.stringify(cat52));

I tried something like:

```
console.log("cat52.value="+cat52.get("value"));
console.log("cat52.label="+cat52.get("label"));
```

And it gives the right value, but not the label.
Label is the control's label, not the selected item's label.

I am new to UI coding and don't even really know what to search to get userful info for this, so hopefully this is not a duplicate..

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

> The `some()` method tests whether some element in the array passes the test implemented by the provided function.

```js
var object = { "_optionsMdl": [{ "label": "558Label", "selected": false, "value": 558 }, { "label": "739Label", "selected": true, "value": 739 }] },
    selectedItem;

object['_optionsMdl'].some(function (a) {
    if(a.selected) {
        selectedItem = a;
        return true;
    }
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(selectedItem, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: I was hoping there's some simple existing method with the object I get from registry.byId() with some parameter that I can call instead of parsing through the _optionMdl values.  I guess there isn't one?

Comment: please, from where is `registry.byId()`?